# Local notification views to appear in foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I need local notifications to display in foreground. I read that this is possible in the introduced in iOS10 `UserNotifications` framework. I try to implement it and get the notifications only in background. In foreground `-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification` gets called but the view of the notification is not shown. I would like it to show on both foreground and background, to be tappable and to trigger a method when tapped. Is this possible and what am I missing in my code if yes. This is the code: 
In AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
center.delegate = self;
UNAuthorizationOptions options = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound;
[center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:options
                      completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                          if (!granted) {
                              NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
                          }
                      }];

return YES;
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
NSLog(@"Will present notification");
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
NSLog(@"Did Receive Notification Response");
}
```

In a ViewController:

```
- (void)locationManagerDidEnterRegionOfCamera:(NSString *)cameraName {
NSDictionary *info = @{ kRegionNotificationDictionaryCameraName : cameraName };

// Check if the switch was previously set to off and not fire notification
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"switch"]) {

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"10.0.0")) {
        UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
        content.title = @"Don't forget";
        content.body = @"Buy some milk";
        content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];

        UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                                                                        repeats:NO];

        NSString *identifier = @"UYLLocalNotification";
        UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier
                                                                              content:content trigger:trigger];

        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@",error);
            } else {

            }
        }];

    } else {
        [NotificationsHelper scheduleRegionNotificationWithInfo:info];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to write `completionHandler(some UNNotificationPresentationOptionsValueAccordingToTheDoc)` at the end of `userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification: withCompletionHandler:`. Calling this block will allow you to decide to show it or not.

Comment: @Larme Thanks, this was it. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important method is this one: `userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:`

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter?language=objc):

> **completionHandler** The block to execute with the presentation option for the notification. Always execute this block at some point
>   during your implementation of this method. Specify an option
>   indicating how you want the system to alert the user, if at all. This
>   block has no return value and takes the following parameter:
>
> **options** The option for notifying the user. Specify `UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone` to silence any alerts. Pass
>   other values to specify which types of alerts you want to allow. For
>   information about the available alert options, see
>   `UNNotificationPresentationOptions`.

Additional Infos on [Apple Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW14)

What's the plan:

Let's say that you receive 2 types of notifications, by you want to handle them differently, for one you want to show the alert even if the app is in foreground, and the other one just a sound.
That's why you use this method.

Analyse the `UNNotification`, and according to your choices, at the end, call `completionHandler(someValue)`, where `someValue` is a [`UNNotificationPresentationOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationpresentationoptions?language=objc) (it's a flag in reality, you should be able to combine them). The one you want at least is `UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert`.

Sample code:

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {
   UNNotificationPresentationOptions options;
   //Read the notification object, parse some info, decide on what do to by settings options
   if (something)
   {
       //Show badge
       options = UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge;
   } 
   else if (somethingElse) 
   {
       //Show alert and make sound
       options = UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert;
   } 
   else ...

   completionHandler(options);
}
```

Comment: an example will be more beneficial

Comment: @XcodianSolangi I added a sample code on how to use it. Note that there is also a sample code on the linked documentation part.